# How to align text to bottom of background image with bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

See this [gist](https://gist.run/?id=68eaf914fc0caec4fb6ff3a9be855d06)

I want to move the text to the bottom of the image as it is easier to read there.

But I have not figured out how to do this.  If I just add margin to the top, then on mobile, it is then too much margin.

```
<div id="home-section" class="image-bg vertical-align">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="home-content padding ">

            <h1 class="jumbo text-center"><em>This is the headline</em></h1>    
            <div class="button text-center">
                <a href="/signup"" onclick="log('click','register','home-section')" class="btn btn-primary btn-animated">Start Free Trail</a>
            </div>
    </div>
</div><!--/#home-section-->
```

css

```
#home-section {
background-color:#7e90a2;
background-image:url(https://traken.net/images/bg/home-bg-3.jpg);
color:#fff;
height:900px;
```

}

Comment: have your tried with position absolute and relative?

Comment: No, how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="home-section" class="image-bg vertical-align">
<div class="container">
    <div class="home-content padding ">

        <h1 class="jumbo text-center"><em>This is the headline</em></h1>    
        <div class="button text-center">
            <a href="/signup"" onclick="log('click','register','home-section')" class="btn btn-primary btn-animated">Start Free Trail</a>
        </div>
</div>
</div><!--/#home-section-->

#home-section {
   background-color:#7e90a2;
   background-image:url(https://traken.net/images/bg/home-bg-3.jpg);
   color:#fff;
   height:900px;
   position:relative;
}
div.home-content {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
}
```

jsfiddle -> https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/145890/

Comment: Plus 1 for the fiddle. Also this one kept the centering correct.

Answer (score 1):

use position absolute for content-padding and position relative for main div #home-section

```
#home-section{
   position: relative;
}

.home-content{
   position: absolute;
   bottom:10px;
   right:10px;
}
```

10px is a basic, you can adjust bottom and right of .home-content to whatever pixels you want.

Comment: awesome solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
#home-section h1{
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```